# NoMethodError when saving Stripe keys to database, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

I'm trying to save my user's Stripe secret and publishable keys to my database upon creation of their managed Stripe account on my site.

**stripe_controller.rb**

```
def create

  Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]
  @account = Stripe::Account.create(
    managed: true,
    country: params[:artist_payment_setting][:country],
    email: @artist.email,
    tos_acceptance: {
      ip: request.remote_ip,
      date: Time.now.to_i
    },
    legal_entity: {
      dob: {
        month: params[:artist_payment_setting][:month],
        day: params[:artist_payment_setting][:day],
        year: params[:artist_payment_setting][:year]
      },
      first_name: params[:artist_payment_setting][:first_name],
      last_name: params[:artist_payment_setting][:last_name],
      type: 'individual',
    }
  )

  if @account.save
    @payment = @artist.create_artist_payment_setting(
        currency: @account.default_currency,
        country: @account.country,
        stripe_id: @account.id,
        stripe_publishable_key: @account.keys.publishable, ***********problem********
        stripe_secret_key: @account.keys.secret            ***********problem********
      )
  end

  redirect_to artist_path(@artist)
end
```

Unfortuntely, I keep getting `NoMethodError (undefined method 'publishable' for #<Array:0x007f57d83edaf0>)` and the same with `secret`.

The API response is

```
{
  keys:
    {
      secret: "secret_key"
      publishable: "publish_key"
    }
 }
```

Can't figure out how to get those keys.

Comment: Have you looked at `@account.keys.inspect` to see what it contains? The error message suggests that it is an `Array`...

Comment: Yeah, I can't figure out why it's coming back as an `Array`. The response from the API is not.

Comment: Try using `byebug` to manipulate `@account.keys` in your console. Can you post what `@account` looks like before its saved?

Comment: `@account` is just the variable I'm using to create a new Stripe account. And the Stripe account is creating no problem, running the `if @account.save` part. It's retrieving the `stripe_id`, `currency`, `country` without problem, but those are not nested. I think having `secret` and `publishable` nested in `keys` is what's throwing it off.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug with Stripe. It seems `@account` acts like a Hash so `@account.keys` returns an array of keys (ironically `[:keys]` in this case) for the object rather than what you'd expect.

This isn't in the documentation, but treating your object like a hash format may fix your problem:

```
@account[:keys][:publishable]
```

Just a heads up, there's a similar bug with the `#capture` method in `Stripe::Payment` since that's a Ruby reserved word as well. Not sure why Stripe is in the habit of using reserved words within their response.

Comment: Just tried that - came back as `NoMethodError (undefined method '[]
' for nil:NilClass)`

Comment: Can you try `@account.to_h`? does it give you the API response you  provided above?